# JSONP Works on browsing to URL but not on refresh

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

On a page I have 2 javascripts. The first script (A.js) appends a script to the head of the parent page in order to pass JSONP. The first script then takes the JSONP array data and puts it into an array for the second script to use. When I go to the hard URL everything works fine. If I F5 it doesn't work. If I add an alert to the first script right after the JSONP is done then everything works.

So, I am guessing that when refreshing, for some reason, everything happens much faster and therefore the appending of the script doesn't have a chance to happen and the array never receives the data.

How can I fix this?

Main Page:

```
<script src="A.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
ArrayValueOnMainPage = ArrayValue.FirstValue
</script>
```

A.js:

```
//Fail safe default
ArrayValue = {"FirstValue":["NULL"]};

function initiate(data){    
    ArrayValue = data;
}

function loadJSONP(url){
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    head.appendChild(script);
}

loadJSONP('/test.json');
```

test.json:

```
initiate({"FirstValue":["Hello"]});
```

On hard browse to URL FirstValue is passed as Hello.

On F5 refresh FirstValue is passed as NULL.

Comment: Everything that needs access to the data has to be in or called from `initiate`. That's the only reliable solution.

Comment: Likely some weirdness from caching. Stuff is already there, so easy to load, and your `ArrayValueOnMainPage` gets processed after `initiate`. You press F5, you request a refresh, stuff starts getting loaded, and the assignment is too early, as the JSONP is not in yet (and `initiate` has, obviously, not processed). As Felix Kling says, whenever you are dealing with async stuff, only ever use things in execution lines flowing from the callback.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a timeout to the "loadJSONP" function in order to break the asynchronous nature of the loading? Or anyway to re-write the code to gt what I am after? The second script on the main page is from another vendor so I can not include that logic into the initiate function.